# Func<> with Interface to send different type of Func<>

Tags: c#

Here is pseudo code for a basic example:

```
// Cannot touch
public class QAS
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Execute<T>(IEnumerable<Point> i) where T : class, IPointResults, new()
    {
        //returns object using IPointResults
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> Execute<T>(IEnumerable<Seg> i) where T : class, ISegResults, new()
    {
        //returns object using ISegResults
    }
}


public interface IPointResults
{
    int turtle;
}

public interface ISegResult
{
    double bird;
}

public interface PointSeg
{
    string id;
}

public class Point : PointSeg
{
    string id;
    int x;
    int y;
}

public class Seg : PointSeg
{
    string id;
    string q;
}
```

I have these two methods which are very similar, I'd like to utilize there generic where clauses by take the similar code and combine it to one:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAttributes<T>(IEnumerable<Point> pts) where T : class, IPointResults, new()
{
    var queryAttributeSet = new QAS();

    var rv = new List<T>();
    var batches = pts.Batch(25);

    Log.Debug($"Attempting to get {total} records using {batches.Count()} requests");

    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        var results = queryAttributeSet.Execute<T>(batch);
        rv.AddRange(results);
    }

    return rv;
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAttributes<T>(IEnumerable<Seg> segments) where T : class, ISegResults, new()
{
    var queryAttributeSet = new QAS();

    var rv = new List<T>();
    var batches = segments.Batch(25);

    Log.Debug($"Attempting to get {total} records using {batches.Count()} requests");

    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        var results = queryAttributeSet.Execute<T>(batch);
        rv.AddRange(results);
    }

    return rv;
}
```

My attempt:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAttributes<T>(IEnumerable<Point> pts) where T : class, IPointResults, new()
{
    return GetAttributesHelper<T>(pts);
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAttributes<T>(IEnumerable<Seg> segments) where T : class, ISegResults, new()
{
    return GetAttributesHelper<T>(segments);
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAttributesHelper<T>(IEnumerable<PointSeg> x) where T : class, new()
{
    var queryAttributeSet = new QAS();

    var rv = new List<T>();
    var batches = x.Batch(25);

    Log.Debug($"Attempting to get {total} records using {batches.Count()} requests");

    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        var results = queryAttributeSet.Execute<T>(batch);
        rv.AddRange(results);
    }

    return rv;
}
```

I try to utilize that `Point` and `Seg` follow the interface `IPointSeg` but unfortunately this doesn't work because QAS.Execute doesn't know how to take in `IPointSeg` and it cannot be modified.

Then I thought maybe if I somehow was able to tell it which function to use by delegates:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAttributes<T>(IEnumerable<Point> pts) where T : class, IPointResults, new()
{
    var queryAttributeSet = new QAS();
    Func<IEnumerable<Point>, T> execute = queryAttributeSet.Execute<T>;
    return GetAttributesHelper<T>(pts, execute);
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAttributes<T>(IEnumerable<Seg> segments) where T : class, ISegResults, new()
{
    var queryAttributeSet = new QAS();
    Func<IEnumerable<Seg>, T> execute = queryAttributeSet.Execute<T>;
    return GetAttributesHelper<T>(segments, execute);
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetAttributesHelper<T>(IEnumerable<PointSeg> x, Func<IEnumerable<PointSeg>, T> execute) where T : class, new()
{
    var rv = new List<T>();
    var batches = x.Batch(25);

    Log.Debug($"Attempting to get {total} records using {batches.Count()} requests");

    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        var results = execute(batch);
        rv.AddRange(results);
    }

    return rv;
}
```

This doesnt work because you cant use an interface in Func<> to as a way to send 2 types of Func<>s to a function.

---

I just want to use QAS.Execute while wrapping the functionality with the batching logic I written and not have it duplicated

Comment: Why not just define the method as `public IEnumerable<T, TT> Execute<T>(IEnumerable<TT> i)`?

Comment: QAS.Execute cannot accept a generic as a parameter, only IEnumerable<Point> or IEnumerable<Seg>